# Concatenate Values from multiple rows in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a file source where the data looks like this:

```
ID BarcodeNumber
------------------------
1  123456789    
1  33    
2  987654321    
2  44
```

I would like to get the data as follows:

```
ID BarcodeNumber
------------------------
1  12345678933    
2  98765432144
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

EDIT: I would like to do this in the data flow as this could potentially have billions of rows.

Comment: For ID 1 how do you determine, that it's 12345678933 and not 33123456789? You can't rely on the order displayed in example when you add an ORDER BY to the query.

Comment: How do you determine order for rows? If you want to do this in dataflow then do this `src -> lookup dest table on id [row exists or not]? if yes -> update table and append incoming value to existing barcode column, if no -> insert row`.

Comment: Good point there is actually a rownumber column that I left out. This rownumber is the order in which they should be concatenated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The desired state is that for each ID, all of the barcodes will be concatenated together.

To accomplish this, your data must be sorted by ID. If the file isn't sorted already, then you'll need to run it through the Sort task.

Once you have sorted data, then you will need to add a Script Transformation in [Asynchronous mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx). It'll be async since the number of rows in will not be the same number as rows out.

The psuedo code will be something like

```
If Row.ID <> LastID
    If LastID <> ""
        Output0Buffer.ID = LastID
        Output0Buffer.Barcodes = Barcodes
    LastID = Row.ID
    Barcodes = ""

Barcodes = Barcodes + Row.Barcodes
```

### Caveats

- The above code is neither C# or VB.NET but the logic should be sound
- If you have billions of rows, you are going to need some serious RAM on this machine as SSIS is an in-memory transformation system.
- The Sort operation and this script task are going to be slow and memory intensive as they cannot re-use memory space

Comment: Thanks for your help. For some reason it appears to be missing the last ID from the data set.
  if (Row.ID != LastID)
        {
            if (LastID != 0)
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                Output0Buffer.ID = LastID;
                Output0Buffer.BarCodeDataCombined = BarCodeDataCombined;
            }
            LastID = Row.ID;
            BarCodeDataCombined = "";
        }
        BarCodeDataCombined = BarCodeDataCombined + Row.BarCodeData;

Comment: Good catch. In the linked article, search for EndOfRowset. You'll need to override the `ProcessInput` for your input buffer and check for the EndOfRowset being true. When that occurs, you'll need to output the final set of LastID and Barcodes.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I am not really a programmer. I tried this but now it doesn't return any rows.

    public override void Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
    {


        if (Buffer.EndOfRowset())
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.ID = LastID;
            Output0Buffer.BarCodeDataCombined = BarCodeDataCombined;
            Output0Buffer.SetEndOfRowset();
        }
    }

Answer (score 4):

[image: Data flow]

Source File:

```
ID,RowNum,Barcode   
1,1,123456789  
1,2,33    
2,1,987654321    
2,2,44
```

Split the rows of the file. For the simple case as assumed in the source file here, we can use the conditional split. for more involved situation, we can use Script component as the splitter. From here on, the solution would be pretty standard wrt sort and merge. Once merged, add a derived column: TRIM(Barcode1) + TRIM(Barcode2) where Barcode1 is coming from the "left side" which has rows with RowNum 1, and Barcode2 from the "right side". If you are concerned about the performance of sort component, put the split rows into two tables, and compare the performance.

```
Cond. Split: RowNum1 (RowNum == "1"), RowNum2 (RowNum == "2")
Sort: By ID; Pass through: Barcode
Merge Join: Left outer join, Join key: ID; Output: ID, Barcode1 and Barcode2
Derived column: TRIM(Barcode1) + TRIM(Barcode2)
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I had gotten the script task to work, but this is a great alternative.